# How do I return from func main in Go?

Tags: go

How do I return from `main` with an exit code as I would in C? *Context:* I'm checking that there is a single command line argument, I will print usage and return an an error status code if the argument count, or argument is invalid.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go uses the [Exit](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) function for that. Just pass the status code as an argument and you're done :)

To `exit(1)` with an error message you can use `log.Fatal()`/`log.Fatalf()`/`log.Fatalln()`: https://pkg.go.dev/log#Fatal

Comment: That may work in many cases but not all: Things as flushing a logger/closing files do _not_ happen when you just os.Exit(). Defers do not run.

Comment: You can do something like this https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent/blob/master/cmd/torrentfs/main.go#L78

Comment: Just be careful that os.Exit() doesn't run the deferred functions ([doc](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit)).

Comment: no way to send a message along with it—i would have to precede the call to Exit() with a Println() yeah?

Comment: @MattiasMartens You're looking for `log.Fatal()`/`log.Fatalf()`/`log.Fatalln()` :)

Answer (score 23):

The correct answer is in the link by Matt Joiner. Essentially the following snippet. One has to ensure that rest of the code does **not** call os.Exit() anywhere, like flag.ExitOnError, log.Fatalf(), etc.

```
func main() { os.Exit(mainReturnWithCode()) }

func mainReturnWithCode() int {
    // do stuff, defer functions, etc.
    return exitcode // a suitable exit code
}
```

Comment: The intention is that you return e.g. 1, 2 or 0 rather than `exitcode`, which is just meant as a placeholder.

Comment: It looks to me Go is a bit flawed if it forces you to write such a function in order to get all "deferred" resource liberations executed. It would have been way easier to just let main() return int, and it is supported in all OSes I know.